# Is $Tf =f(x+4)$ and $Tf=f(x)+4$ a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have a transformation $T: \mathcal C^0 \rightarrow \mathcal C^0, Tf:=f(x+4)$ and I want to determine if this is linear. As far as I know I need to show that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication and that it contains the zero element. I am just not sure about the actual "proof".

**My attempt:**

For it to be linear, $f(u)+f(v)=f(u+v)$ and $f(cu) = cf(u) $ needs to hold. Set $f=u+v$. $T(u)=f(u+1)$. $T(v)=f(v+1)$

$$\implies T(u+v)=f(u+v) \not= f(u)+f(v) \implies \text{not a linear map}$$

Similarly for $f(x)+4$ the map is not linear. Am I applying the critera correctly? In other words. If I am given some transformation or function $f(x)$ do I just "plug in" $(u+v)$ and see if $f(u)+f(v)=f(u+v)$ holds?

Comment: You need to take two functions $f$ and $g$ and check that $T(f+g) = Tf + Tg$. It is not what you did here

Comment: @StratosFair I don't understand. Could you maybe elaborate.

Comment: for any function $f$, $Tf$ is a function. So for $T$ to be linear you need to check that the function $T(f+g)$ is equal to the function $Tf + Tg$ for any two $f$ and $g$, i.e. you need to check that for all $x$
$$[T(f+g)](x) = [Tf](x) + [Tg](x) $$

Comment: @TheCount For the function $f$ to be linear, it must hold that $f(u + v) = f(u) + f(v)$. Of course, not every $f \in \mathcal C^0$ is linear. However, $u$ and $v$ (as you have used them in your question) are inputs to the function $f$, **not the function $T$**. The inputs to $T$ are **functions**. In order for $T$ to be linear, it must hold that $T(f + g) = T(f) + T(g)$ for any two **functions** $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is, and I mean this in the best possible way, a mess. But that's OK, we live to learn! Here are the problems with your attempt.

1. You start with "for it to be linear, $f(u)+f(v) = f(u+v)$. This is unclear. What do you mean by "it" in the sentence "for *it* to be linear"? The condition you write is the condition for $f$ to be linear, but you *should* be examining the linearity of $T$, not $f$.
2. You then say "set $f=u+v$, but what are $u$ and $v$? Are they numbers? Functions? Mappings? Elephants?
3. Then you write the equation $T(u) = f(u+1)$ which is completely nonsensical. You do not write where this equation comes from, nor does it make any sense. In order for $T(u)$ to be a sensible expression, $u$ would need to be a function, since $T$ operates on functions, but in order for $f(u+1)$ to be sensible expression, $u$ would need to be a number! So which is it?
4. Then you write the even less comprehensible conclusion that $f(u+v)\neq f(u)+f(b)$. Where the heck did this conclusion come from? You never even calculated what $f(u+v)$ is, how can you claim it is not equal to $f(u)+f(v)$? Also, what does the expression $f(u+v)$ even mean? I thought we started with $f=u+v$?

Like I said, a total mess.

---

In order to properly do the proof, you need to first do a couple of things:

1. Stand up.
2. Take a walk or make yourself some coffee or maybe read a couple of pages of a book.
3. Make sure your head is cleared.

OK, done? Now let's get down to business. Follow the steps below:

1. Write down the **exact** definition, in words or symbols, of when a mapping is linear. No, that's not just "it's linear when $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$ and $f(cv)=cf(v)$. The exact definition starts with "let $U, V$ be vector spaces and let $M:U\to V$. Then, $M$ is linear if, **for all**..... and so on.
2. Write down, using the above definition, with exact and precise wording, when $T$ in your question is linear.
3. Stare at what you wrote down, and if you are still stuck, let me know by writing a comment here (and edit your question with how far you got).

Good luck!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140186/discussion-on-answer-by-5xum-is-tf-fx4-and-tffx4-a-linear-map).